# Magento 2 - Get Value of Attribute Set in Cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, attributes, cart

How do I calculate the total value of products in the cart belonging to a specific attribute set?
I need to disable the checkout and 'Proceed to Checkout' link if the total value of products in the cart, belonging to a specific attribute set is below a certain amount.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should create a custom attribute for the product and use the cart rules that magento 2 manages basically

Cheers